# Yargs not working when using import in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, yargs

I'm new to Node.js and I'm learning some basics now. I'm trying to use some typescript code to convert into .js code later.

I wrote this simple code to test

```
    import * as fs from 'fs'


    const argv = require('yargs')
                .alias('f', 'filename')
                .alias('c', 'content')
                .demandOption('filename')
                .demandOption('content')
                .argv

    fs.writeFile(argv.filename, argv.content, (error)=>{
        if(error) 
            throw error
        console.log(`File ${argv.filename} saved.`)
    })
```

And this works fine. But when I change the line *require('yargs')* to import, like below:

```
   import * as fs from 'fs'
   import * as yargs from 'yargs'

    const argv = yargs
                .alias('f', 'filename')
                .alias('c', 'content')
                .demandOption('filename')
                .demandOption('content')
                .argv

    fs.writeFile(argv.filename, argv.content, (error)=>{
        if(error) 
            throw error
        console.log(`File ${argv.filename} saved.`)
    })
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Buffer | URL'.

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'URL': hash, host, hostname, href, and 9 more.ts(2345)
```

Does anybody know what's the difference between using module/import that is causing this error? For fs library both ways work fine in this example.

Comment: Refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: "in ES6, yargs is no longer a singleton, so you need to call yargs() to get an instance of yargs, at which point the API is identical, here's a simple example:"
https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1854

Answer (score 9):

Here is the corrected code for anyone still wondering how to use ES6 module syntax with Yargs. I had to add some type information with option() to avoid errors. Refer to [a Github discussion](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1854#issuecomment-787509517) for more information.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import _yargs from 'yargs';
import { hideBin } from 'yargs/helpers';
const yargs = _yargs(hideBin(process.argv));

(async () => {
    const argv = await yargs
        .option('filename', { type: 'string', require: true })
        .option('content', { type: 'string', require: true })
        .alias('f', 'filename')
        .alias('c', 'content')
        .argv;

    fs.writeFile(argv.filename, '' + argv.content, error => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(`File ${argv.filename} saved.`);
    });
})();
```

Comment: this has all the correct parts for me to get past my error, I compared to what I was trying to do and fixed. I converted const yargs  = require('yargs/yargs')  to  import yargs from 'yargs/yargs';  which throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing yargs typings, by running the following command?

npm install --save @types/yargs

Answer (score 1):

I think ES6 compliant import is still not supported and only require works.

```
import yargs from 'yargs'
console.log(yargs.argv)

$ node app.js
undefined
```

Comment: Why not `console.log(yargs)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the type of args from argv. Try to change your core to:

```
const argv = yargs
        .option('filename', {
            alias: 'f',
            demandOption: true,
            describe: 'Nome do arquivo',
            type: 'string'
        })
        .option('content', {
            alias: 'c',
            demandOption: true,
            describe: 'Conteudo',
            type: 'string'
        })
        .argv
```

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for scripts that cannot be run without external dependencies or platforms. Use proper code formatting [Ctrl+K] instead: single backticks (“`”) for one-liners, property names and methods, code fences (“````”) for code blocks. Also please avoid chit-chat in questions, SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A website.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution to use Yargs with module type

```
import yargs from 'yargs/yargs';  // (v17.7.2)

const argv = yargs(process.argv.slice(2))
    .option('dev', {
        alias: 'd',
        type: 'boolean',
        describe: 'dev mode'
    })
    .argv;

console.log(argv.dev); // will be true when starting "node index.js --dev"
```

source for typescript, usable in NodeJS with "type": "module" https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/docs/typescript.md